# Insecure update error - SUPublicDSAKeyFile

Tags: mojave, software-update, error

A minute ago I had the following popup appear:

[image: Insecure update error]

> **Insecure update error!**
>   For security reasons, the file (dsa_pub.pem) indicated by the 'SUPublicDSAKeyFile' key needs to exist in the bundle's Resources.

I have no idea what application generates this error. If I open up the Console and search for "SUPublicDSAKeyFile" or other strings, I don't find anything.

**How can I find out what this is about?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error comes from the Sparkle Update system (SU). It is a freely available system for integration by developers into apps to provide online updating of their apps.

The error message you see could come from any of your third party apps that are using Sparkle (it is very popular).

The error message indicates that an important file is missing from the application's bundle. This usually indicates developer error (i.e. the program you've downloaded was "flawed" to begin with) - or it could be caused by you manually deleting the file.

I would start with Activity Monitor to see which third party apps you're running, and simply try closing down app after app until you're left with the one responsible for this popup.

Comment: Thanks. My main concern is that this doesn't mean trouble (malware). I have a suspicion that this is F-Secure XFence, which I tried to remove but that failed partly, and this might be the result of that. But I guess it's safe to click it away and leave it at that for now.

Comment: It is not malware, no. The message is safe to ignore - the only disadvantage is that this specific program won’t be able to automatically download its updates online. You’ll need to update it manually, if you want to keep it.

Answer (score 6):

To see which app is using this library run this in terminal

```
find /Applications -name Sparkle.framework
```

the you will get something like:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework
/Applications/ForkLift.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework
/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework
```